# bind: loading from master file failed: file not found

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, bind

So I'm kinda a newbie and I'm following [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-bind-as-a-private-network-dns-server-on-ubuntu-16-04#top) to connect a domain to my server. here is my codes:

named.conf.options:

```
acl "trusted" {
        124.243.241.164;
        124.243.241.164;
        124.243.241.164;
        124.243.241.164;
};


options {
    directory "/var/cache/bind";

    recursion yes;                 
    allow-recursion { trusted; };  
    listen-on { 124.243.241.164; };  
    allow-transfer { none; };      

    forwarders {
            8.8.8.8;
            8.8.4.4;
    };


    dnssec-validation auto;

    auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
    listen-on-v6 { any; };
};
```

named.conf.local:

```
zone "ns1.raze.one" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/zones/db.ns1.raze.one";
        allow-transfer { 124.243.241.164; };
 };
zone "243.124.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/zones/db.124.243";
        allow-transfer { 124.243.241.164; };
 };
```

db.124.243:

```
;
; BIND reverse data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL    604800
@   IN  SOA ns1.raze.one. root.ns1.raze.one. (
                  3     ; Serial
             604800     ; Refresh
              86400     ; Retry
            2419200     ; Expire
             604800 )   ; Negative Cache TTL
; name servers - NS records
      IN      NS      ns1.ns1.raze.one.
      IN      NS      ns2.ns2.raze.one.
; PTR Records
164.241   IN      PTR     ns1.ns1.raze.one.    ; 124.243.241.164
164.241   IN      PTR     ns2.ns2.raze.one.    ; 124.243.241.164
164.241   IN      PTR     rdn.mercury.orderbox-dns.com.  ; 124.243.241.164
164.241   IN      PTR     rdn.venus.orderbox-dns.com.  ; 124.243.241.164
```

db.ns1.raze.one:

```
;
; BIND data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL    604800
@   IN  SOA ns1.raze.one. root.ns1.raze.one. (
                  5     ; Serial
             604800     ; Refresh
              86400     ; Retry
            2419200     ; Expire
             604800 )   ; Negative Cache TTL
; name servers - NS records
    IN      NS      ns1.ns1.raze.one.
    IN      NS      ns2.ns1.raze.one.
; name servers - A records
ns1.ns1.raze.one.          IN      A       124.243.241.164
ns2.ns2.raze.one.          IN      A       124.243.241.164

; 124.243.241.164 - A records
rdn.mercury.orderbox-dns.com.        IN      A      124.243.241.164
rdn.venus.orderbox-dns.com.        IN      A      124.243.241.164
```

Now the problem is when I enter `sudo named-checkzone ns1.raze.one db.ns1.raze.one` I get this error:

```
zone ns1.raze.one/IN: loading from master file db.ns1.raze.one failed: file not found
zone ns1.raze.one/IN: not loaded due to errors.
```

although this file does exist!
and when I do `sudo named-checkzone 124.243.in-addr.arpa /etc/bind/zones/db.124.243` it's working:

```
zone 124.243.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 3
OK
```

I'm stuck at this for while I would appreciate a little help here.

Comment: You have one command with a relative path that fails with a "file not found" error and one with an absolute path that works, what is the current directory?

Comment: Did Tom's answer solved your issue? If not, could you edit your question or comment on his answer so the community can help you further?

Answer (score 6):

It's just a wild guess but with the `directory` statement pointing to */var/cache/bind/* it will search there for the files if you specify a relative path name. Either specify the absolute path as you did, or modify the `directory` statement.

Comment: The answer helped me; I'd just add that instead of `sudo named-checkzone ns1.raze.one db.ns1.raze.one`, it should be `sudo named-checkzone /etc/bind/zones/ns1.raze.one db.ns1.raze.one` in OP's case (it may be difficult to orient yourself when someone simply says "use absolute paths instead of relative", as I was looking into the confs and not on the command itself).

Needless to say, bind9 respects the directory in the configuration file, only the `named-checkzone` utility doesn't, for some reason.

Comment: @pydoge: is this still the case? Perhaps you could file a bug report with ISC?